# Using java how to add in-code generated jpg images to a word document without saving the file first

Tags: java, ms-word, jpeg

Using java how can I add in-code generated jpg images to a word document without saving the file first.
The word document needs to be created from scratch in Java (poi does not seem to do the images).

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you have an in-memory representation of the Word document in Java, or is the word doc existing on the filesystem? Is it a binary .doc, or a docx (if the latter, docx4j will help)

Comment: The word document needs to be created from scratch in Java (poi does not seem to do the images)

Comment: With docx4j you can easily create docx from scratch in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments on my question from plutext and trying this out. The docx4j is working really good.